# Cocoa app name isn't displayed in "Force Quit Applications" window

Tags: macos, cocoa

my Mac app works as a Menu Item application, and you can toggle the dock icon on and off in the settings. 
If the dock icon is shown, it shows the app name.

[image: dock icon shows app name]

But if I open the "Force Quit Applications" window, the app name isn't shown.

[image: App name not shown in Force Quit Application window]

Where does that window get the name from?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is the `CFBundleName` from your info.plist file. I just created a new test app from scratch and after launching it I'm able to see it in the "Force quit applications" window out of the box (OS X El Capitan 10.11.2)

[image]

Comment: Hi Stavash, I can confirm it's the CFBundleName, when editing the info.plist  shown as "Bundle display name". No idea why it was empty.. Thanks!